# SSL error on XAMPP

Tags: apache, ssl

I installed ssl on XAMPP just fine. When I try to start Apache in the Xampp Control Panel, it says the following error:

```
(localhost:80) You configured HTTPS(443) on the standard HTTP(80) port!
```

Which is weird beacuse I created a domain that uses ssl, not localhost. My `httpd-ssl.conf` is as follows... (not the entire file, but VirtualHost directive)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/secure/movies/public_html"
    ServerName www.movies.local
    ServerAlias movies.local

    SSLEngineOn on

    SSLCertificateFile      "C:/xampp/htdocs/secure/resources/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   "C:/xampp/htdocs/secure/resources/server.key"
    SSLCACertificateFile    "C:/xampp/htdocs/secure/resources/ca_client.crt"

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/secure/movies/public_html">
    Options Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    SSLRequireSSL
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 1
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I tried investigating alot for the past 3 hours but nothing on this error. Also, so there would be no confusion, in `httpd-ssl.conf` it listens to port 443 and in `httpd.conf` it listens to port 80.

Comment: "...not the entire file, but VirtualHost directive..." - the error is probably in the other parts of the config which you did not show.

Comment: well i didn't change anything, i just added VirtualHost to httpd-ssl.conf

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo in that config:

SSLEngineOn on

should be

SSLEngine On